# Overriding Custom Actions in a Web Setup Installer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation, setup-project, web-setup-project

I am trying to override the "Commit" action in my "Installer" class for my web set up project, for the purpose of opening the website after the installation is completed successfully. While the same concepts works in a setup project for a  windows application, it seems that for my web project, the installer class is being ignored. 
Is it possible to override the installer class in a web-setup project?